# Rails ID and order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3 app. How would I find only records with an id of "1" and put them in DESC order? I feel like this is a simple question but I can't figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not understand why would you need to order only one record, the solution (provided that I understood) that solves your question is:

```
Item.where("id = 1").order("id DESC").first
# => Item Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```